# How can I access the tree in my printpostroder function?

Tags: c, memory-management, tree, tree-traversal

This is my tree struct :

```
    typedef struct quad 
{
    struct quad *child[4];
    char *names;
} quad;
```

and I need to build it then print it in postorder
but I can't access the memory for the tree in my printpostorder function :

```
void printpostorder(quad * tree)  
    {
       if (tree->names[0] == 'G') {      
        printpostorder(tree->child[0]); 
        printpostorder(tree->child[1]); 
        printpostorder(tree->child[2]); 
        printpostorder(tree->child[3]); 
        
        printf("%s", tree->names);
        }
        else {
        printf("%s", tree->names);
        }
    }
```

I can access it before calling this function in the main function.

```
int main(void){
    
   int n = 0;
   int size;
   quad * t;
   char * str1 = (char *)malloc(MAX * sizeof(char));
   printf("Enter name: ");
   scanf("%s", str1);
   size = strlen(str1);
   t = build_preorder_tree(str1,t,&n,size);
   printpostorder(t);
   
   
}
```

here is the build tree function, basically we have to build from preorder, then print out the post order.

```
quad* build_preorder_tree(char *s_r, quad * tree, int * index_ptr,int size){
    
    char c;
    int s = 0;
    int index = *index_ptr;
    c = s_r[index];
    char d = ']';
    char * ptr = (char *)malloc(MAX * sizeof(char));
    char * ptr1;
    
    if(index == size){
        return;
    }
    
    tree = malloc(sizeof(quad*));
    tree -> names = (char *)malloc(MAX * sizeof(char));
    

    if(c == 'G') {
     tree->names = "G";
     (*index_ptr)++;
     tree->child[SW] = build_preorder_tree(s_r, tree->child[SW],index_ptr,size);
     tree->child[SE] = build_preorder_tree(s_r, tree->child[SE],index_ptr,size);
     tree->child[NW] = build_preorder_tree(s_r, tree->child[NW],index_ptr,size);
     tree->child[NE] = build_preorder_tree(s_r, tree->child[NE],index_ptr,size);
     
    } 
    if(c == 'W') {
        tree->names = "W";
        (*index_ptr)++;
    }
    if(c == 'B') {
        strcpy(ptr,s_r);
        ptr1 = strtok(ptr+index,"]");
        strncat(ptr1,&d,1);
        s = strlen(ptr1);
        (*index_ptr)= (*index_ptr) + s;
        tree->names  = ptr1;
        
    }
    
     
    
 return tree;
 
}
```

And when I call the printpostorder(t), a seg fault occurred at first call of
`if (tree->names[0] == 'G')`

I tried to access the tree before the printpostorder is call, and I was able to access every element of the tree

Comment: I have dynamically allocated memory in my build_preorder_tree functionn

Comment: Your compiler should give a warning that this line is incorrect: `printpostorder(&t);`. The function parameter needs to be `quad *` but you are passing in a `quad **`.

Comment: Ok now that you have changed the code the problem is no longer the same. Now you need to explain what "can't access the memory" means. Does it crash? Does it print wrong results? We also need to see the `build_preorder_tree` definition. That is, provide a [minimal verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Also, use a debugger. It will tell you immediately and exactly which line of code triggers the seg fault and that's the minimum info you should know for yourself and also to be included into the question.

Comment: Now is the perfect time to learn [debugging techniques](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/), including the most important tool you'll ever use as a programmer: your debugger.

Comment: I've used GDB to debug this code, it stops right at the if statement of printpostorder function and a sigsegv segmentation fault is reported

Comment: Yes, and what else? Continue to debug. For example, is it the first call of `printpostorder` or is it one of the recursive calls that seg faults? Is the `tree` pointer a valid value? etc. If you need further help please provide a [minimal verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Without that we can only guess - my guess is your tree build function has errrors.

Comment: it crashed at first call of `printpostorder`, I also checked the tree pointer before the function is call and its valid, and I am able to access `tree->names[0]`

Comment: `tree = malloc(sizeof(quad*))` should be `tree = malloc(sizeof(quad))`